# Can an EV3 power a buggy motor with the NXT to 9V extension cable?

Tags: ev3, motor, electronics

On Philo's motor comparison webpage, https://www.philohome.com/motors/motorcomp.htm, it says that the buggy motor (42908 lego id, 5292 bricklink id) is not recommended to be powered by an RCX as the RCX cannot provide enough current for the beast.

How about an EV3 with the NXT to 9V conversion cable (bricklink id x1676)? Could the EV3 power the beast (both interested in the EV3 powered by rechargeable batteries or powerful AA batteries)?

Has anyone seen such setup? I cannot find any data about how much current the EV3 can deliver...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The motor drivers are protected by resettable fuses. Each fuse protects two output ports (A/B or C/D). The amount of current that can be delivered depends on the time that it is applied. The 1.1A listed in the schematic is the max sustained current. The [datasheet](https://www.bourns.com/docs/product-datasheets/mfmsmf.pdf) for the resettable fuses provides more details.

The 2.2A trip current listed in the data sheet is still less than the 3.2A stall current for the motor, so the EV3 will probably struggle with this motor.

[image: electrical schematic]

Note: The full EV3 schematic is included in the *Hardware Developer Kit* available for download on the [official LEGO MINDSTORMS download page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads).

Comment: Max sustained current 1.1A and Philo says 1.4 A for a loaded motor seems also problematic even when not stalling, no ? The load I have in mind is likely greater or equal than what Philo tested..